# PIXI.js - png image resource is not loaded as image/texture, MIME type set, but without extension

Tags: pixi.js

does anybody know how to force PIXI load PNG file without PNG extension as a  Sprite? Please note that this image is quite big - 2048x2048px.

Problem is, that image is generated by ASP.NET MVC controller and the result is based on parameters.

Here's how my resources.background onject looks like in google developer console:

```
Resource
  crossOrigin: ""
  data: " PNG  IHDE    0sRGB   gAMA... etc"
  error: null
  isAudio: false
  isDataUrl: false
  isImage: false
  isJson: false
  isVideo: false
  isXml: false
  loadType: 1
  metadata: Object
  name: "background"
  url: "http://localhost/controller/action/123?param1=png&param2=false"
  xhr: XMLHttpRequest
  xhrType: "text"
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, that `xhrType` is set to `"text"`. Also `responseType` is set to `"text"`

Workaround (not clearly described in documentation) is setting up options for Loader.

```
var loaderOptions = {
    loadType: PIXI.loaders.Resource.LOAD_TYPE.IMAGE,
    xhrType: PIXI.loaders.Resource.XHR_RESPONSE_TYPE.BLOB
};

var imageLoader = new PIXI.loaders.Loader()
imageLoader.add("background", "http://pathToImage/noExtension?p=a", loaderOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

For v6 it seems to be slightly different by the way:

```
const loaderOptions = {
    loadType: PIXI.LoaderResource.LOAD_TYPE.IMAGE,
    xhrType: PIXI.LoaderResource.XHR_RESPONSE_TYPE.BLOB
};
```